# Issues with ConversationChain in Langchain: Repeating Last Response on Simple User Inputs

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain, azure-openai

I've been developing a RAG chatbot using AzureOpenAI and recently started integrating Langchain into my project. However, I'm encountering an issue where the output quality has decreased compared to when I was using the vanilla LLM. I'm relatively new to Langchain, so there might be aspects of its functioning that I'm not fully grasping yet. I would appreciate any guidance or insights.

Here's the situation:

I'm running both a ConversationChain instance and a standard AzureChatOpenAI instance simultaneously for comparison purposes.
Most functionalities seem to be working fine. However, when the user input is a simple "Thanks!", like when I want to end a conversation, the ConversationChain instance just repeats the last response. Vanilla LLM on the other hand responds something like "My pleasure! Please let me know if you have more questions", which is a type of answer I would expect. This is the only scenario where this odd behavior occurs.
The memory implementation appears to be correct, and regular conversations ie. questions, proceed without issues.
Below is the relevant portion of my code where I call both the chain and the plain LLM. The context_list is a list I obtain from AzureSearch, which is then passed to the prompt. The prompt is designed to accept only 1 variable: `context` input variable, human question is in `query`. I've included some commented-out code to show an alternative prompt implementation that resulted in the same output.

```
    def rag(self, context_list: list[str], query:str) -> str:

        context = "\n\n".join(context_list)

        # Format the message template with the actual context
        formatted_chatbot_sys_msg = self.env_loader.CHATBOT_SYSTEM_MESSAGE.format(context=context)
        # from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

        # chat_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        #     [
        #         SystemMessage(content=(formatted_chatbot_sys_msg)),
        #         HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{query}"),
        #     ]
        # )
        # messages = chat_template.format_messages(query=query)
        
        messages = [
            SystemMessage(content=formatted_chatbot_sys_msg),
            HumanMessage(content=query),
        ]

        res = self.conversational_llm(messages).content
        with get_openai_callback() as cb:
            # Run the chain and calculate the cost
            response = self.conversation(messages)["response"]
            
            print(cb.total_tokens)

        return response
```

```
        self.conversational_llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
                                model=self.env_loader.AZURE_OPENAI_CHATGPT_DEPLOYMENT,
                                api_version=self.env_loader.AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION,
                                temperature=self.env_loader.TEMPERATURE,
                                max_tokens=self.env_loader.MAX_TOKENS,
                                n=self.env_loader.N_
                                )
        self.history = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(return_messages=True, k=5, memory_key="history")
        
        self.conversation = ConversationChain(
                                llm=self.conversational_llm,
                                verbose=True,
                                memory=self.history
                                )
```